# What is the purpose of popen, and why would fdopen and fgets work better in certain situations?

Tags: c, pipe, popen, fgets

I understand that popen opens the pipe like a file to allow reads/writes, but wouldn't fdopen and fputs/fgets be more efficient?

Comment: your question doesn't look ok?

Comment: Use fgets instead of popen? They are not in the same ballpark, not in the same league, and not even the same sport :)

Comment: Both popen and fgets are unrelated.

Comment: Oh, I see. Well I mean why would it be better to use fdopen with fgets and fputs instead of using popen with read/write. I am using pipes to communicate with my processes and I am thinking fputs and fgets are a better choice...

Comment: You should be able to open with `popen()` and read/write with `fputs()/fgets()`...

Comment: The 'p' stands for process, not pipe. The manual pages are pretty clear on why fdopen and popen serve very different purposes -- popen takes a command line to execute.

Comment: 'popen with read/write' -- why would you use read/write with popen, when popen is a stdio routine? Please, do at least a minimal amount of reading of the man pages before you ask a question. You wrote 'I understand that popen opens the pipe like a file' -- but that understanding is completely wrong. popen creates a pipe, starts a shell with the pipe attached, and does an fdopen or equivalent with the other end of the pipe. You can of course do the same thing yourself.

Answer (score 2):

**[popen](http://linux.die.net/man/3/popen)**

> The popen() function opens a process by creating a pipe, forking, and invoking the shell

**[fgets](http://linux.die.net/man/3/fgets)**

> fgets() reads in at most one less than size characters from stream and stores them into the buffer pointed to by s.

`popen` opens a pipe, `fgets` reads data. One doesn't work "better" than the other because they do different things. I guess you could say `popen` is better if you want to open a pipe, while `fgets` is better if you want to read data, but that's pushing it.

Comment: You can happily use `fgets()` to read from a file stream created by `popen("...", "r")`.

Comment: [Yes, yes you can.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13410871/what-is-the-purpose-of-popen-and-why-would-fdopen-and-fgets-work-better-in-cert/13410932#comment18324314_13410871)

Answer (score 2):

The [man page for popen](http://linux.die.net/man/3/popen): *opens a process by creating a pipe, forking, and invoking the shell.*

The [man page for fopen](http://linux.die.net/man/3/fopen): *opens the file whose name is the string pointed to by path and associates a stream with it.*

The [man page for fgets](https://www.php.net/fgets): *reads in at most one less than size characters from stream and stores them into the buffer pointed to by s.*

`popen` is used to to open a pipe (usually to execute something like a shell command), and `fopen` is used to open a file that you can then use `fgets` to read from.

So `popen` and `fgets` are different functions that serve different purposes.

Comment: @Duck: sorry, all those f&*#ing "p's" got me confused and I jumped into PHP mode.  Updated my answer to use the man pages instead.  But in my defense, in both C and PHP the function names are the same, the logic is the same, the purpose for each is the same, and there were a ton of damn 'p's

Comment: You can happily use `fgets()` to read from a file stream created by `popen("...", "r")`.

Comment: @BenVoigt `fopen` does what this answer says it does. The answer could include `fdopen` *also*, since the OP mentioned it.

Comment: @Jim: The question *didn't* mention `fopen`.  `fdopen` is considerably more useful for exchanging data with a forked process through pipes, just like `popen` does.

Comment: @BenVoigt You're telling me things that are obvious and that I already know, things that in no way counter my previous comment i.e., it's a strawman and pointless chatter.